# Why are these attributes being written in reversed order?

Tags: qt

I'm working with `QDomElement` and `QDomDocument` to export data to XML. When I do this, the attributes get written in the correct order:

```
element.setAttribute("xRepeat", xrepeat);
element.setAttribute("yRepeat", yrepeat);
```

This outputs something like `xRepeat="3" yRepeat="8"`. Then I tried this...

```
element.setAttribute("xrepeat", xrepeat);
element.setAttribute("yrepeat", yrepeat);
```

The resulting output is `yrepeat="8" xrepeat="3"`. Is there a reason why the attributes are being written in reversed order now? I already did the usual clean/qmake/build routine in my IDE (Qt Creator) to make sure that the compiler's "only rebuild what was changed" feature wasn't doing any weird stuff

Comment: Why does it matter? It probably uses unordered collection underneath.

Comment: It doesn't matter to my program, but it's more legible the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or empty-element tag is not significant. Don't rely on software that requires a specfic order.

Comment: I don't, but it's more legible the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Cat Plus Plus is correct. 
QDomElement uses a [QHash](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qhash.html) underneath to store element attributes.  QT Doc states that

> With QHash, the items are arbitrarily
>   ordered

When you change key you also change the order.